# Push/pull notifications for inbox messages in the android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, android-app

Can we have notifications for when we get um, notifications, in the inbox that when clicked open up the inbox/relevent inbox message within the android app?

Ideally settings could be added to control the frequency of these or turn them off entirely either per notification type (badge, new answer, new @comment etc.) or globally.

Comment: We are pushing notifications to your phone any time items are pushed to your inbox.  Are you not seeing these?

Comment: No. I've definately not seen this one. Next time I notice one on the web I won't open the box (so I don't mark it as read) and I'll see if the app has a 1 in the top right for the notification at least. When I open the notification screen in the app I can see the notifications, I just don't get an android notification message.

Comment: Just checked in app configuration (where you would uninstall the app in android) and "Show Notifications" is ticked. I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S2 btw.

Comment: Wow, this was a good catch - I'll answer in a bit after you receive this notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bit funny (to me anyway).  During early development we had coded a sanity check so that only Employees of Stack Exchange were eligible to receive push notifications.  It took me awhile to find this because from all of my testing it was working perfectly.  It has now been released to all alpha testers.

Comment: Ah that explains it. Looks like it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, is there  a via app name now when posting from App?